# Exists - Invalid statement. Please check aliases, field identifiers, projections and query conditions

Tags: node.js, join, dynamic, cloud, storage

I'm using Dynamicloud and something is wrong in my code:

**This is my code:**

```
    var query = provider.createQuery(modelId);
    query.alias = 'outer';

    var existsCondition = dc.conditions.exists(modelId, 'inner');
    existsCondition.add(dc.conditions.equals('outer.id', '$inner.id$'));

    query.add(existsCondition).orderBy("outer.id").desc();

    query.getResults(function (error, results) {
        console.log(results);
    });
```

**This code throws the following Exception:**

```
Invalid statement.  Please check aliases, field identifiers, projections and query conditions.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi**

Dynamicloud handles reserved words and you're using `inner` and `outer` words which are reserved words.

**Try the following code:**

```
    var query = provider.createQuery(modelId);
    query.alias = 'o';

    var existsCondition = dc.conditions.exists(modelId, 'i');
    existsCondition.add(dc.conditions.equals('o.id', '$i.id$'));

    query.add(existsCondition).orderBy("o.id").desc();

    query.getResults(function (error, results) {
        console.log(results);
    });
```